# Factorializing a number with .reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, mapreduce, factorial

I am trying to write a function that will produce the factorial of a provided integer and then reduce the factorial array (by multiplying each array element).

For example:

factor(5) >>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] >>> 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 >>> 120

```
var array = [ ];

function factor(num) {
  for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }  
  array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  })
};

factor(5);
```

However, it keeps returning undefined.

I think it has to do with the formatting of the function, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to pass the `initial value` for reduce,

```
array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
},1);
```

Also return the reduced value of the `array` from the `function`,

```
function factor(num) {
  for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }  
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  },1)
};

console.log(factor(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem that your function does not actually return any value, and the "return" value of such a function is `undefined`. Let's look at why this is happening:

```
function factor(num) {
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        array.push(i);
    }   
    array.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a * b; // <-- Here is probably your misunderstanding
    });
};
```

That return that I marked returns from the function that you pass to reduce(), but there is *no* return from factor().

Answer (score 2):

`.reduce()` is not necessary to return expected results. Try utilizing single `for` loop

```js
var array = [];

function factor(num) { 
  for (var i = 1, res = 1; i < num; array[i - 1] = i, res *= ++i);
  return res
};

console.log(
  factor(3)
, factor(4)
, factor(5)
, factor(6)
, array
)
```

Answer (score 0):

using Array indexes and reduce if anybody doesnt want to fill their arrays with ordered numbers.

```js
num = 10;

Array(num).fill(null).reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    if (i == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return acc * (i + 1);
}, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function factor(num) {
  return Array(num)
    .fill(null)
    .map((item, index) => index + 1)
    .reduce((pv, cv) => pv * cv);
}

console.log(factor(3), factor(4), factor(5), factor(6));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.